# c# change background color for Toast content XML schema for ToastNotificationManager

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, toast, xmldocument

I'm using windows ToastNotificationManager,
right now I create the toast UI like

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04)
```

is there a way I can change the background to white or any color
also for the text element, can I change the font style, color or size
can I even use my own XmlDocuments,I tried but I get system error

Comment: Don't add both `UWP` or `WPF` tags...It will be enough if you add only one :)

Comment: Okie dokie :), I just added it cause I had one more free tag :D

Comment: and about the question , I didn't use `ToastNotificationManager` before but if you can gain access to it's templae/Control Template, then yes you can(only if such property is not available)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#text-elements
=========================
I tried but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the background color of toasts. If you're writing a UWP app, you can do more flexible things with your toast, see the [toast content documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) to learn more.

The adaptive content section in that article illustrates how you can do some more advanced text formatting (with a few different text sizes).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Toast Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/root-elements) defined in the documentation you cannot set a background colour of the toast itself or it's elements, as link answers aren't allowed here's a list of elements supported:

- toast
- visual
- binding
- image
- text
- audio
- commands
- command

You can add ms-contrast for images to support standard, black or white but that's for images only. You can find out more about the Toast Scheme from the [Toast Content Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema) page